# Yarn doesn't authenticate Gitlab Private package

Tags: npm, gitlab, yarnpkg

I have two private packages hosted on GitLab. One of the installs correctly the other one gives error 404 which in my experience at GitLab means unauthorised

- I've checked with `yarn install --verbose` that it is using the right registry
- I've cleared the cache of yarn
- I've tried npm
- I've tried adding both project level tokens and instance level tokens

This is my `.yarnrc`

```
"@myscope:registry" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/"
"//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken" token
always-auth true
lastUpdateCheck 1660229364662
```

And this is my `.npmrc`

```
"@myscope:registry"="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/"
"//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken"="token"

always-auth=true
```

Note that these are in my home directory. This is intentional because if I add them at project level I need to use an env var but that complicates things a lot because this project is build as part of a Gradle task

Also note that the first project had similar problems when I wanted to install it the first time but then I managed to get it solved. I'm not sure what I've done or what helped at the end but since then it installs without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was an issue with GitLab because I generated a new token and it works now. (I don't have an expiration date set so..)